# Facing trouble in adding space

Tags: android, space

I want to add separator between 'TextView's. Two 'Space's are there, the last one works fine, but the first one takes large space horizontally. I am attaching a screenshot. I don't understand what is causing the problem. Can any one say what is happening there. Thanks in advance.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">
    <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Type here"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_search"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:contentDescription="Search image"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Issue is with Table Layout. Better change your main layout to Linear

Comment: @Neo is table layout necessory

Comment: Give android:layout_column="1" in your Textview id android:id="@+id/btn_previous" and your issue will be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give **`android:layout_column="1"`** in your Textview id **`android:id="@+id/btn_previous"`** and your issue will be solved

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Type here" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:contentDescription="Search image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Previous"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that worked thank you @Prem. But could you please tell me the reason. As it is the first column of the row then numbering should start with zero, right? Will you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

> ImageButton width and weight

and Table row

> weightSum

try this

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:hint="Type here" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="Search image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Previous"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0d0f21"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Benijith, you are right. But could you please tell me what's the problem if I want the ImageButton width to be wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

If you does not required the `Tablelayout` you can use `LinearLayout`
easily understandable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tl_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Type here"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/search_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="Search image"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0d0f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek for your time, this is also a very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` as parent with `layout_width = "match_parent"` and `layout_height = "wrap_content"` and give `layout_width = "0dp"` and `layout_weight = "1"` to each button and use `layout_margin="2dp"` for the centre button.

I mean, Do it like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Previous"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
    />

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Thank you @Parambir for your time. You have provided a very simple and nice solution.

Comment: I truly wanted to upvote your answer, but as my reputation is below 15, I am unable to do that. I am very sorry @Parambir and thanks again for your support...

Answer (score 0):

**main_activity.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Previous"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/ractangle_drawable_pitch"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/ractangle_drawable_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/ractangle_drawable_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**ractangle_drawable_pitch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FF686D" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <size android:height="10dp" />

</shape>
```

**ractangle_drawable_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#32BEBB" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <size android:height="40dp" />

</shape>
```

**ractangle_drawable_blue.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#0000ff" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<size android:height="10dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Hope this may helps you.

Comment: Thank you @InsaneCat for your support, this is also a nice solution

Comment: @Neo Welcome. hope this may help you.if it yes then mark as a right this answer and give a vote so it's helpful yo others.happy to help you.

Comment: As my problem was with TableLayout thus I am accepting Prem's answer. I also wanted to accept Benjith binja's answer too. But as I can accept only accept only one answer thus I couldn't accept both the answer.  
I truly wanted to upvote your answer, but as my reputation is below 15, I am unable to do that. I am very sorry @InsaneCat and thanks again for your support...